# git ignore vendor directory in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, git, zend-framework2

All,

I have a module in "vendor" directory. I don't want to check in any contents in the vendor directory. So, I changed my .gitIgnore file like this:

```
nbproject
._*
.~lock.*
.buildpath
.DS_Store
.idea
.project
.settings
composer.lock
vendor
```

But, git is still recognizing the vendor directory as modified and asking me to check it in.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Had you previously checked vendor stuff in to git? If so you need to remove it with `git rm`

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I followed both of them and they worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add directories to your `.gitignore` directory followed by a "/".

```
tim@roflcopter ~/htdocs/laravel $ cat .gitignore | grep vendor/
vendor/
```